# Why is my array restructured?

Tags: javascript, object

I have hit a bit of a snafu. I have a global variable (I wish I could avoid it, but I don't see how) that at some point corrupts. I have looked all over my code and nowhere is the variable manipulated other than where and how I want it too. To make things even odder, when I put the following line in my script (place seems inconsequential) `console.log(_var); debugger;` and then right after type in `_var` in the console myself, the first _var show the correct structure, but the second doesn't...

Here's was the original object looks like (and is supposed to look like):

```
[1: Array[2], 4: Array[2], 5: Array[2], 7: Array[2], 8: Array[2], 9: Array[2], 10: Array[2], 11: Array[2], 12: Array[2], 13: Array[2], 14: Array[2]]
```

And here is what the object looks like after the breakpoint:

```
[undefined × 1, Array[2], undefined × 2, Array[2], Array[2], undefined × 1, Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening, but when I loop through this object in a function that's called based on a user action at a later point, this is giving me issues.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: is this coming from PHP?

Comment: Where's there rest of the code?

Comment: Are you saying `console.log(_var)` prints `[1: Array[2], 4: Array[2], 5: Array[2], 7: Array[2], 8: Array[2], 9: Array[2], 10: Array[2], 11: Array[2], 12: Array[2], 13: Array[2], 14: Array[2]]`

Comment: 1) This is in javascript (see tag). 2) I don't know if the rest of the code is relevant...perhaps you can tell me what part of the code you would like to see. @Kevin ) Yes.

Comment: @Battle_707 All the code that uses `_var` - a [mcve] that lets us reproduce the situation

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5r9cgn0r/ repro

Comment: Your title says it's an object, but your output is for an array. Which is it?

Comment: @Barmar you are right. That's a...typo on my behalf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no problem here. You're just seeing two different ways of displaying the same array. `console.log` is labeling elements with their indexes and omitting unassigned array indexes, while just typing `_var` into the console is showing unassigned indexes as `undefined × howevermany`.

For anyone who thinks this doesn't look like a Javascript array, it's simple to reproduce this behavior in the Chrome console:

[image: Example session]

Comment: @KevinJantzer It sounds weird and looks like a consistency bug in the console, but it's right…

Comment: You are right @user2357112...This is rather odd, but I can recreate the effect. Means that the issue I'm having is caused by something else though... :S. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinJantzer why do you think so? The `log` implementation is up to the implementer and that's how the Chrome developers chose to do it. For the record, in Firefox, you will get the same output whether you have `_var` or `console.log(_var)`. Neither of the two is inherently _correct_ as they are just different ways to show the same data.